# Magento 2 add to wish list event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, wishlist

I would like to customize the add to wish list functionality from my custom module In magento 2.

Actually i need **custom options** chosen and **product id** when i wishlist a product. i have found a link for list of magento 2 events below https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/ please suggest me how to achieve this?

I have written code as shown below the event has been calling perfect but i unable to get the **product id and custom options** how to get in the observer?

**app/code/Demo/Pricecalculations/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="wishlist_add_product">
       <observer name="Demo_Pricecalculations_Wishlistproduct" instance="Demo\Pricecalculations\Observer\Wishlistproduct" />
   </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Demo/Pricecalculations/Observer/**

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Pricecalculations\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
class Wishlistproduct implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/Wishlist.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("custom Wishlist function has been Calling");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**`wishlist_add_product`** give us  3 parameters

```
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'wishlist_add_product',
            ['wishlist' => $wishlist, 'product' => $product, 'item' => $result]
        );
```

- wishlist : it give customer wishlist object.. At observer you can get
  wish object by `$observer->getEvent()->getWishlist();`
- product: it give customer just  added product object. At observer you
  can get product object by `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();`
- item: current add wishtlist  item . At observer you can get product
  object by `$observer->getEvent()->getItem();`

So, at observe you can product id from `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId()`

Comment: Wonderful, you saved my day!